# User function with named dataframe not found when used within purrr::map

Tags: r

If I create my own function, and state the name of the dataframe I want to use within that function, when I then use this within the map function, it says the dataframe isn't available even though I have created it before I get to use my function.

```
library(tidyverse)
filter_fn <- function(){
  iris1%>%
  filter(Sepal.Length <4)}

map(.x=list("setosa","virginica"), .f = function(species){
  iris1 <- filter(iris, Species %in% species)
  iris2 <- filter_fn()
  return(iris2)
})
```

I can't understand why this is, can anyone explain why this would be?

Comment: R uses lexical scoping. This means that "free" variables in functions are looked up where the function is defined, not where the function is called. `iris1` is a free variable in your `filter_fn` function. Rather than relying on global variables like that, why not make the data.frame a parameter to your function so you don't have to worry about the scope.

Comment: it works when its not being iterated over within the map function though?

Comment: Sure, because then you are defining `iris1` in the global scope. But when you define it in the anonymous function inside the map, it's no longer in the global scope and your `function_fn` function is defined in the global scope. You can read more about lexical scoping here: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lexical-scoping

Comment: so anything being run inside map is no longer in the global scope

Comment: That's one way of looking at it. That's not super unique to map. It's more about calling functions from inside other functions. It's better if you write your functions as "pure" functions which accept all the data they need as parameters and return new values without having invisible global dependencies or side effects.

Comment: if this was rewritten as a loop then it would work: species <- c("setosa","virginica");
for (i in seq_along(species)){
iris1 <- filter(iris, Species ==species[i])
iris2 <- filter_fn()
print(iris2)
}

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the comments made already, I modified your code using a few additional tools to illustrate:

```r
library(tidyverse)
filter_fn <- function(){
  rlang::env_print() # added to print information about the environment
  iris1%>%
    filter(Sepal.Length <4)}

# safely added so errors do not prevent code from running
walk(.x=list("setosa","virginica"), .f = safely(function(species){
  iris1 <- filter(iris, Species %in% species)
  iris2 <- filter_fn()
  return(iris2)
}))
# <environment: 0x000001e006004828>
# Parent: <environment: global>
# <environment: 0x000001e006b9ef98>
# Parent: <environment: global>
```

From this you can see information about the execution environment (`0x000001e006004828` and `0x000001e006b9ef98`) for each iteration when `filter_fn` is called.

There are no bindings in the execution environments. R will check the parent environment for `iris1` next -- the global environment in this case. Since it is not there either it cannot find `iris1` and errors.

Comment: so it seems that R will look for `iris1` in the environment in which the function was created. `filter_fn` was created in the global environment, R looks for `iris1` in the global environment which doesn't exist there hence the error message. if `filter_fn` was moved to within the anonymous function then it would work.

Comment: @Basil Yes, your proposal *would* work. In that instance the anonymous function environment will be bound to `filter_fn()` as the *function environment*. Since you create `iris1` in the function environment the scoping will find this object. That being said, I would not recommend it. I think it is cleaner and clearer (to you in the future or other users) to pass it as a function argument: `filter_fn <- function(iris1){...` and then when you call it: `iris2 <- filter_fn(iris1)`.